# Adding new node connected to set of newly added nodes

Tags: graph, neo4j, cypher, neo4j-apoc

I need a query which does the following things:

1. Insert a varaible number of nodes if they don't exist
2. If there isn't already a node which has a relation to all nodes added in 1 create this node and connect it to nodes from one

The general idea is that the variable number of nodes describe a unique event which I want to aggregate by inserting the new node.
So if I first insert 4 nodes by this

```
MERGE (k:type1 {data: "data1"})
MERGE (a:type2 {data: "data2"})
MERGE (m:type3 {data: "data3l"})
MERGE (p:type4 {data: "data4s"})
WITH [a, m, p, k] AS myList
CALL apoc.lock.nodes(myList) // let's lock ahead this time
WITH head(myList) as first, myList
OPTIONAL MATCH (d:SomeLabel)-[:REL]->(first)
WHERE all(node in tail(myList) WHERE (d)-[:REL]->(node))
WITH first, myList
WHERE d IS NULL
MERGE (d:SomeLabel)-[:REL]->(first)
FOREACH (node in tail(myList) | MERGE (d)-[:REL]->(node))
```

If I change the first node the graph looks as expected:

```
MERGE (a:type2 {data: "data2"})
MERGE (m:type3 {data: "data3l"})
MERGE (p:type4 {data: "data4s"})
WITH [a, m, p, k] AS myList
CALL apoc.lock.nodes(myList) // let's lock ahead this time
WITH head(myList) as first, myList
OPTIONAL MATCH (d:SomeLabel)-[:REL]->(first)
WHERE all(node in tail(myList) WHERE (d)-[:REL]->(node))
WITH first, myList
WHERE d IS NULL
MERGE (d:SomeLabel)-[:REL]->(first)
FOREACH (node in tail(myList) | MERGE (d)-[:REL]->(node))
```

[Correct graph](https://i.stack.imgur.com/HkuMM.png)

However when changing for example the content of the second node, a new common node is not added

```
MERGE (k:type1 {data: "data1"})
MERGE (a:type2 {data: "data22"})
MERGE (m:type3 {data: "data3l"})
MERGE (p:type4 {data: "data4s"})
WITH [a, m, p, k] AS myList
CALL apoc.lock.nodes(myList) // let's lock ahead this time
WITH head(myList) as first, myList
OPTIONAL MATCH (d:SomeLabel)-[:REL]->(first)
WHERE all(node in tail(myList) WHERE (d)-[:REL]->(node))
WITH first, myList
WHERE d IS NULL
MERGE (d:SomeLabel)-[:REL]->(first)
FOREACH (node in tail(myList) | MERGE (d)-[:REL]->(node))
```

[Incorrect graph](https://i.stack.imgur.com/zOUot.png)

Also, after this has been done I want to add another node connected to the new common node

I used @Graphileon's answer for my solution

```
MERGE (a:type2 {data: "data2"})
MERGE (m:type3 {data: "data3l"})
MERGE (p:type4 {data: "data4s"})
WITH [a, m, p, k] AS things
OPTIONAL MATCH (c:Collection)
WHERE apoc.coll.isEqualCollection([(c)-[:REL]->(thing)|thing],things)
WITH things,COALESCE(id(c),-1) AS idC, id(c) as center

CALL apoc.do.when(
      idC = -1,
      'CREATE (c:Collection) '
      + 'FOREACH(m IN $things | MERGE (c)-[:REL]->(m) ) '
      + 'MERGE (s:sample)-[:REL]->(c)',
      '',
      {things:things}
) YIELD value
RETURN value.node as node;
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Did you consider this approach:

```
WITH ['a','b','c','d'] AS thingNames
FOREACH( thingName in thingNames |
    MERGE (n:Thing {name:thingName})
) 
WITH thingNames
MATCH (n:Thing) WHERE n.name IN thingNames
WITH COLLECT(n) AS things
OPTIONAL MATCH (c:Collection)
WHERE apoc.coll.isEqualCollection([(c)-[:REL]->(thing)|thing],things)
WITH things,c,COALESCE(id(c),-1) AS idC

CALL apoc.do.when(
      idC = -1,
      'CREATE (c:Collection) '
      +' FOREACH(m IN $things | MERGE (c)-[:REL]->(m) )'
      +' RETURN c',
      '',
      {things:things}
) YIELD value

RETURN COALESCE(c, value.c) AS collectionNode
```

it creates a new `:Collection` node for every new combination of Things

[image]

Comment: Thank you. I used your approach to get a query that works for me. How do I use the collection node if it already exists. In that case I would like to do something like 
`MERGE (s)-[:REL]->(c)`

Comment: @newjoiner1234 can you define  "use"?  From your question, it does not seem that something has to be MERGEd or CREATEd. BTW, if my answer provides the solution to your question, please accept it.

Comment: I am very new to cypher but I hope I can give an idea of what I want to do
```
CALL apoc.do.when(
      idC = -1,
      'CREATE (c:Collection) '
      + 'FOREACH(m IN $things | MERGE (c)-[:REL]->(m) ) '
      + 'MERGE (s:sample)-[:REL]->(c)',
      'MERGE (s:samp)-[:REL]->(c)',
      {things:things}
) YIELD value
```

Comment: I updated the answer so that in any case, it returns the collection node.